# How to add regline to df.plot.scatter

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I've done df.plot.scatter like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':y_pred, 'y':y_test})
df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter', s=50)
```

[image]

I want to add regline & i have no idea how to do this

of course I can do by sns.lmplot as bellow

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', data = data)
```

[image]

but i like df.plot.scatter style

python 3

Comment: what do you mean by regline?

Comment: @jlarsch I've edited the post